# can insert update and delete data in laravel api using React native(Android) is it possible?

Tags: laravel, react-native, api

i known this question is very Strange but do what I didn't get an answer anywhere So that's it I asked this question Thought it necessary to ask !! can insert update and delete data in laravel api using React  native is it possible ?  I have a website In which i used the larval api That's why I question I am asking !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes can do this easily first make database in MySQL, second is create insert Update query in larval and make it controller in larval and using axios lib in react native to create post and get method.

Answer (score 0):

If you able to make request with API like update the user data and if you have implemented that in your API then you can for sure edit data and delete them using API request. I suggest using requests in your React native Application.

Comment: Okay ! give me a demo of code and  Give me the document link I go there and read it